# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (57:2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

> FetchPlanet.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { ListGroup, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./components.css";
import ListSelected from "./ListSelected";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
export default class FetchPlanets extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      planets: null,
      selectedPlanets: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://assignment-machstatz.herokuapp.com/planet";
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.setState({ planets: data, loading: false });
    console.log(this.state.planets);
  }
  fetch = e => {
    const data = this.state.selectedPlanets;
    data.push(e.target.innerText);
    this.setState({
      selectedPlanets: data
    });
  };

  render() {
    const splanets = this.state.selectedPlanets.map(function(item) {
      return <li> {item} </li>;
    });
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
<Container fluid>
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="listplanets" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">

  <Tab eventKey="listplanets" title="Planets List">
  {this.state.loading || !this.state.planets ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
            <ListGroup>
              {this.state.planets.map((planetnames, index) => {
                return (
                  <ListGroup.Item
                    onClick={e => {
                      this.fetch(e);
                    }}
                    className="selectlg"
                  >
                    {planetnames.id}
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                );
              })}    
  </ListGroup>
  </Tab>

  <Tab eventKey="selectedplanets" title="Selected Planets">
  <ul>
            <li>{splanets}</li>
          </ul>    
  </Tab>
  </Tabs>
        </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
  }
}
```

** Did you want a JSX fragment <>...? (57:2), Here I'm trying to create react-Bootstrap tabs, but I'm getting error as adjacent jsx elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. I used Div tag also but it didn't help. I used React.Fragment also... still of no use**

Comment: It will help you avoid typos to use reasonable and consistent code indentation. All due respect, the free-for-all above lends itself to this sort of problem. *(**Not** my downvote. Seems unnecessary to me.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `)}` after `</ListGroup>`

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { ListGroup, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./components.css";
import ListSelected from "./ListSelected";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
export default class FetchPlanets extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      planets: null,
      selectedPlanets: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://assignment-machstatz.herokuapp.com/planet";
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.setState({ planets: data, loading: false });
    console.log(this.state.planets);
  }
  fetch = e => {
    const data = this.state.selectedPlanets;
    data.push(e.target.innerText);
    this.setState({
      selectedPlanets: data
    });
  };

  render() {
    const splanets = this.state.selectedPlanets.map(function(item) {
      return <li> {item} </li>;
    });
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
<Container fluid>
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="listplanets" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">

  <Tab eventKey="listplanets" title="Planets List">
  {this.state.loading || !this.state.planets ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
            <ListGroup>
              {this.state.planets.map((planetnames, index) => {
                return (
                  <ListGroup.Item
                    onClick={e => {
                      this.fetch(e);
                    }}
                    className="selectlg"
                  >
                    {planetnames.id}
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                );
              })}    
  </ListGroup>
   )}
  </Tab>

  <Tab eventKey="selectedplanets" title="Selected Planets">
  <ul>
            <li>{splanets}</li>
          </ul>    
  </Tab>
  </Tabs>
        </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's very good of you to help, but typos don't get *answers* on SO, they get helpful comments and close votes. (And: Well-spotted! I could see there was some JSX problem, but hadn't got to the specific typo yet.)